# Where are files created in a docker container stored?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a python script in one of my docker containers. I'm trying to log errors that occur during execution of the script:

```
with open('logs.txt', 'a+') as filehandle:
    filehandle.write('Error message here')
```

Locally, `logs.txt` is created when I run : `python path/to/script.py`. However, when I run the script from docker like so; `docker-compose exec service_name python path/to/script.py`, I can't locate the logs file.

I have gone through a lot of documentation about bound mounts, volumes and other stuff. However, none of these are helping.

I need help with locating the `logs.txt` file. It'd also be great to get info about the 'right way' of storing such data.

Edit: Here's what I've tried so far

I already tried to explore the contents of my container via: `docker exec -it container_name /bin/sh`. I still couldn't find `logs.txt`.

PS: I'm new to docker, so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: try to access bash using command `docker exec -it [CONATAINER_NAME] bash` it will provide you bash access to your linux inside docker. then you can try to find `log.txt` using linux command to find logs file.

Comment: Can you post your `docker-compose.yml` or `Dockerfile` with question.

Comment: first, get the docker id by `docker container ls`. Suppose the container id is `38xxxx..` After that go into the terminal of the container by `docker container exec -it 38 bash`. Then you will be inside the container. Then you can navigate to different directories by `cd`. Note: If the bash is not install then you can install bash `sudo docker container exec -it 38 apt install bash`. This depends on the OS you are using. In some cases you will get bash by default, but not necessary.

Comment: @Epsi95 and Akash senta I edited the question to address your proposed solutions.

Comment: I am not sure where is your script is. You can simply navigate using `cd` to check where is the script. If you are not using any persistent storage, the .txt file should be right there.

Comment: Isn't it a better idea to stream logs to a database that's part of a Stateful Set?